# ASP.NET - what is the meaning of <%@ and <asp:Panel?

Tags: asp.net

In the generated asp.net code from visual web developer 2010, I see the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Header" %>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <img alt="xxx" 
            src="Images/bird.jpg" 
            width="800" height="110"/>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel id="menuPanel" runat="server">
        <a href="1.aspx">Home</a> |
        <a href="2.aspx">Titles</a> |
        <a href="3.aspx">Authors</a> |
        <a href="4.aspx">Publishers</a>
    </asp:Panel>
```

1. What is the meaning of `<%@` in
   asp.net?
2. What is the meaning of `<asp:Panel`?

I see other examples, `<asp:Button` `<asp:Label`, etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET server instructions are enclosed by angled brackets: `<% ... %>`; they tell ASP.NET to process their contents before sending a page to the client's browser.

`@` identifies a [**directive**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8syafc7.aspx), which do a variety of things but usually provide some instructions about what to do with the .aspx or .ascx file: [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) and [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b.aspx) are two of the most commonly-used directives.

[`<asp:Panel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) is an ASP.NET [WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.aspx). Web controls are server-side representations of HTML elements. They allow you to manipulate the page in a code-behind file that's executed on the server before being delivered to the client's browser.

For example, ASP.NET renders `Panel` tags as `<div>` elements, and renders [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) tags as `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

`<asp:panel` is a Panel

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx

`<asp:button` is a button

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx\

```
<@% Creates an association between a tag prefix and a custom control
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1) The `<%@` is used to reference a user control that you can add to your page.
2) The `<asp:Panel` is just a container, in HTML it gets generated as a div. The panel has other properties, but in the end it is just a container.

Overall, anything with `<asp` is some form of ASP.NET web control.

Answer (score 1):

Tags starting with asp:SomeName declare server controls. A server control is simply a control that is understood by the server. From w3schools:

HTML server controls are HTML tags understood by the server.

HTML elements in ASP.NET files are, by default, treated as text. To make these elements programmable, add a runat="server" attribute to the HTML element. This attribute indicates that the element should be treated as a server control. The id attribute is added to identify the server control. The id reference can be used to manipulate the server control at run time.